# VM1686:2 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 456 Promise.then (async) (anonymous)

Tags: javascript, json, api, d3.js, jsonresponse

I am building my first real project and using D3.js library for visualization. I was trying to deploy a Bar Chart in D3.js but I am having some problem in my JSON response in d3.json() function. Here is my code:

```
d3.json("<?=  base_url(). "/testingGraph";?>").then( function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

The response looks good, with status of 200. Here is a look into it:
Response:
[image]
Preview:
[image]
But the console Tab is giving following errors:

```
VM1686:2 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 456
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous)
```

Here is my Controller sending the data:

```
    public function testingGraph()
    {
        $db = \Config\Database::connect();

        $dataTableQuery = $db->query("SELECT agent_name, COUNT(id) as transfer FROM `transfers` GROUP BY agent_name ORDER BY transfer DESC LIMIT 10");
        $result = $dataTableQuery->getResultArray();
        echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
```

By the looks of it, I feel I have done everything right, but I can not seem to find the solution to the issue. My response is JSON from PHP, and the preview and status looks good to me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your screenshot shows a  bunch of  `<script>` and `<style>` tags under the JSON. Seems like that's what's causing the "unexpected <"

Comment: @JLRishe it is? Why is it even there? Although I am using Codeigniter 4, but on this specific page, I am not using any other page as inheritance.  Do you know what could be the issue if this is the issue?

Comment: No idea. I haven't used Codeigniter. It looks like some kind of "debugbar" is being inserted into the response. Do you have any idea where that would be coming from?

Comment: @JLRishe absolutely not, I have used so many API calls before and there has never been a response like that. Never in my other requests before, I have come across this. But now I'll shift the focus of my R&D

Comment: Looks relevant: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-75778.html Seems to be a Codeigniter feature.

Comment: @JLRishe thanks. I actually just came across [link](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-74553.html) this and was able to solve. You were right, the Codeingiter's debugger was breaking my json response.